# How to access common base class property to each derived class member

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Please accept apologize if this question might sound stupid. I want to achieve the similar functionality present in .NET class hierarchy by availability of ToString() method of each class member. Let me explain it in details through some code snippet.

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : ParentClass
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public DerivedClass derived = new DerivedClass();

    public void Test()
    {
        // I want to get/set base class member property as follows:
        derived.FirstName.Visible = true;
        derived.LastName.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

What I want is to access base class property associated with each derived class member and can be get/set accordingly.

Comment: Please don't put screenshots of your code, put the code directly.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that inheritence does not work in the way you are trying to implement it. Inheritence is really designed to add more details to some sort of object to create a a digestible mental model of what you are trying to represent. One of the classic examples of this is thinking of the parent class as something like `Vehicle` and the derived class as something like `Motorcycle` or `Ambulence`. In this way you can you could assign additional properties to `Ambulence` or `Motorcycle` that make sense for those specific vehicle types. Here is a quick example of how inheritence is generally intended to be used:

```cs
class Vehicle // all properties common to vehicles
{
   public string Engine { get; set; }
   public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
   public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

}

class Ambulence : Vehicle // ambulence specific properties
{
   public int SirenVoulme { get; set; }
}

class Motorcycle : Vehicle // motorcycle specific properties
{ 
   public bool HasSaddleBags { get; set; }
}
```

That said, you might be able to achieve what I think you are trying to accomplish in the main class if you rearrange things a bit. Rather than using inheritence, you can use composition. This simply means using the `Parent` type inside the `Derived` type, and perhaps renaming them to match their new purpose/intent.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var composed = new ComposedClass();
        
        composed.FirstName = new ParentClass();
        composed.LastName = new ParentClass();
        
        composed.FirstName.Value = "John";
        composed.FirstName.Visible = true;

        composed.LastName.Value = "Doe";
        composed.LastName.Visible = false;
        
        string fullName = $"{composed.FirstName.Value} {derived.LastName.Value}";
        Console.WriteLine(fullName);
        
        bool firstNameVisible = composed.FirstName.Visible;
        Console.WriteLine(firstNameVisible);
        
        bool lastNameVisible = composed.LastName.Visible;
        Console.WriteLine(lastNameVisible);
    }
}

public class DataClass // formerly ParentClass
{
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ComposedClass // formerly DerivedClas
{
    public ParentClass FirstName { get; set; }
    public ParentClass LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
John Doe
True
False
```

you can play with this here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fwDRy0

Comment: You beat me to it by about 5 mins!! :)  Although I would suggest renaming "Parent" and "derived" as they now don't make sense in this context.

Comment: @user1770517 There is a whole theory dedicated to "wrapping" primitives known as Object Calisthenics which were first introduced by Jeff Bay in the book "The ThoughtWorks Anthology".  You can google this to find out more

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith, goog suggestion! I wanted to keep it clear how/where things changed, but it is pretty confusing reading it standalone. I updated with the suggested rename.